# Compiling CoffeeScript with a Cakefile

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, coffeescript

Currently i use this to compile it to a file:

```
task 'CurrentVillage', 'Build Current Vilage', ->
  remaining = appFiles.length
  appContents = new Array remaining  
  for file, index in appFiles then do (file, index) ->
    fs.readFile "media/coffee/#{file}.coffee", 'utf8', (err, fileContents) ->
      throw err if err
      appContents[index] = fileContents
      process() if --remaining is 0
  process = ->
    fs.writeFile 'media/coffee/frontend/VillageCanvas.coffee', appContents.join('\n\n'), 'utf8', (err) ->
      throw err if err
```

I dont get it to compile it directly to javascript :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your tasks in a `Cakefile`, then invoke that Cakefile. Run `cake build` in your terminal from the directory where your coffeescript files reside, after putting a `Cakefile` in the same directory. Here's a simple template for a Cakefile. It already has the build function written in as described below: http://twilson63.github.com/cakefile-template/

```
build = (watch, callback) ->
  if typeof watch is 'function'
    callback = watch
    watch = false

  options = ['-c', '-b', '-o', 'lib', 'src']
  options.unshift '-w' if watch
  launch 'coffee', options, callback
```

Comment: The problem this compiles only files in src. i want to compile the combined code. i do not want to save the combined coffee file.

Comment: Put the `Cakefile` the the root of your directory then and run `cake build` from there.

Answer (score 1):

what connor said (got an upvote from me).

as an alternative you could use [grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/) with the[grunt-coffee plugin](https://github.com/avalade/grunt-coffee) if you want to use the "atthemomentstandardjavascriptbuildtool" ;-)